# how to fix android scrollView height?

Tags: android, button, scrollview

I'm trying to create a layout with multiple buttons, But all buttons was not displayed on Screen, So i used scroll view but now i have one problem because of background image (which is of high resolution). Now i'm getting very large empty space under after buttons. Please suggest a solution how can i fix scrollView hight so that it doesn't show the space under buttons.

like This :[Area with white background is Moblie visible screen and off white area is background image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aNh4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to use an appropriately sized image. If you only want to display part of the image, but the image is a high resolution image, then you are wasting resources by loading the entire image.

You could enclose the ScrollView within another View, and set the background of your parent view to be whatever background you desire. Set the height of both views correctly and you should achieve your desired result.

The hierarchy would be

- View (with background image)

  - ScrollView with buttons

Comment: @Arsalan If it solves your issue, you should hit the little checkbox beside the answer to accept it. (This helps you get better answers, and helps others find them.) You should also do this for your other 4 questions.